# create list with initialized results of variables instead of integer

Tags: python, list, loops, integer, initializer-list

I would like to know how I could create a list with defined variables.

I tried to create a loop but unfortunately, the content of the new list is only the integer of the variables instead of the value I’ve initialized before.

The result I want to reach is a list of the initialized values without the integer. I have had a result like (integer: value) but this is also not my target. I only want to have the initialized value in the list.

**Code:**

```
weight = {} 

weight[0] = 16

weight[1] = 4

weight[2] = 12

weight[3] = 5

weight[4] = 9

weight[5] = 2

my_list = []
for i in weight:
    my_list.append(i)
print(my_list)
```

**output:**
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

**target:**
`[16, 4, 12, 5, 9, 2]`

Comment: Use `for i in weight.values():` or, better, `my_list = list(weight.values())` without any loop

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is initalizing a dictionary and iterating through the keys.
The solution would be:

```
weight = {}

weight[0] = 16

weight[1] = 4

weight[2] = 12

weight[3] = 5

weight[4] = 9

weight[5] = 2

my_list = []
for i in weight.values():
    my_list.append(i)
print(my_list)
```

Or initalize the elements in an array:

```
weights = [16, 4, 12,  5, 9, 2]
print(weights)
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, ty!

Comment: `my_list.extend(weight.values())` would avoid the loop. And `my_list = my_list + list(weight.values())` also works. And if `my_list` is empty (or newly created) just assign it directly: `my_list = list(weight.values())`